# Doctrine2: many-to-many joined entities, multiple andWhere or join WITH clauses?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, multiple-conditions

Two doctrine2 entities, Photo and Tag, are linked by a many-to-many relationship, and mapped accordingly.

Each tag has a key and a value, so an example key is 'photo-type' and an example value 'people'.

I have created a custom repository PhotoRepository.php, to facilitate easy searching for photos with either an array (or a comma-separated list*) of tag pairs, extract below:

```
 public function getQueryByTags($tags = null, $limit =0, $start =-1, $boolean ="and")
   {
    ...
        $qb->select('p')
                ->from('MyBundle\Entity\Photo', 'p')
                ->join('p.tags','t');
                # ->join('a.tags','t')
        if ($boolean == "and") { $qb->where('1 = 1'); }
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if ($boolean == "and") { 
                $qb->andWhere('t.key = ?'.$i.' AND t.value = ?'.($i+1));
            } elseif ($boolean == "or") { 
                $qb->orWhere('t.key = ?'.$i.' AND t.value = ?'.($i+1));
            }
            $qb->setParameter($i, $tag['key'])->setParameter(($i+1), $tag['value']);
            $i += 2;
        }
    ...
      return $qb->getQuery();
   }
```

This works fine for a single tag. However, once tags are multiple (e.g. searching for 'photo-type'=>'people', 'person'=>'Bob'), the boolean logic breaks down and no results are return.

My suspicion is this is something to do with putting together andWhere/(orWhere) clauses from the joined Tag entity with the Doctrine2 queryBuilder(). (Since the same Tag cannot be both 'photo-type'=>'people' AND 'person'=>'Bob', although the same Photo should be).

```
    $photos = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Photo')->
            findByTags(array(
                array('key' => 'context','value' => $context),
                array('key' => 'photo-type','value' => 'field'),
            ));
```

I tried to construct a JOIN WITH query instead, but this seems to require a very complex construction to create the expression, which I haven't been able to figure out:-

```
public function getQueryByTags($tags = null, $limit =0, $start =-1, $boolean ="and")
    {
    ...
        $qb->select('p')
                ->from('MyBundle\Entity\Photo', 'p');
        $i = 1;
        $expr = $qb->expr();

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if ($boolean == "and") { 
                $expr = $expr->andX($qb->expr()->eq('t.key', '?'.$i),$qb->expr()->eq('t.value', '?'.($i+1)));                    
            } elseif ($boolean == "or") { 
            }
            $qb->setParameter($i, $tag['key'])->setParameter(($i+1), $tag['value']);
            $i += 2;
        }

        $qb->join('p.tags','t',Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,$expr);
                # ->join('a.tags','t')
      ...
      return $qb->getQuery();
   }
```

---

EDIT: Ultimately the result set I want is either:

- "and" search: `SELECT all Photos which have (Tag with key(A) AND value(B) ) AND (another Tag with key(C) AND value(D))`
- "or" search: `SELECT all Photos which have (Tag with key(A) AND value(B) ) OR (another Tag with key(C) AND value(D))`
- in which: A, B is the first unique tag 'pair' (e.g. 'photo-type'='people' or 'photo-type'='animal') and C, D is another unique tag 'pair' (e.g. 'person'='Bob', 'person'='Tiddles' or, theoretically 'animal'='Tiddles')

---

Can anyone help me either figure out how to construct this complex JOIN WITH expression?

Or, if it seems like I'm barking up the wrong tree, can anyone suggest an alternative more elegant way to do things?

*NB: If $tags is received as comma-separated string (e.g. $tags="photo-type=people,person=Bob") it is first converted into an array.

---

EDIT#2: the Tag entity, on request from @Wilt:

Tag.yml

```
MyBundle\Entity\Tag:
    type: entity
    table: tag
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: true
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        key:
            type: string
            length: 20
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
        value:
            type: string
            length: 50
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
    manyToMany:
        photos:
            targetEntity: Tag
            mappedBy: tags
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Photo.yml (extract only)

```
MyBundle\Entity\Photo:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: MyBundle\Entity\PhotoRepository
    table: photo
    fields:
        sha1:
....
    manyToMany:
        tags:
            targetEntity: Tag
            inversedBy: photos
            joinTable:
                name: x_photo_tag
                joinColumns:
                    photo_sha1:
                        referencedColumnName: sha1
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    tag_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: To explain the logic of the two-part Tag: —— In theory this tag pair could be modelled as a single unique string (instead of a unique `Tag: key, value`; a unique `Tag: 'key=value'`) but the nature of the data source (external to the web app) makes storing key and value separately simpler for sorting. (ie. one can sort on either key or value fields). –– It also allows the app to identify other objects to link the tag values back to (e.g. 'person','Bob' or 'person','Jill' to a 'Person' object by some index).

Comment: Is it okay to add the tags `'photo-type'='people'` and `'animal'='Tiddles'` on one picture? Otherwise I would suggest changing your model to have people pictures that have people tags and animal pictures with animal tags. It will make all this much easier.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to have `'photo-type'='people'` and `'animal'='Tiddles'` because the tags are human-created and not semantically predetermined by the db model. (These tag pairs are just examples).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks way too complicated for something like this.
You can use native doctrine solutions for this checking of your tag type with a in array solution:

```
$array = [];
foreach ($tags as $i => $tag) {
    $array[] = $tag['value'];
}
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->innerJoin('p.tags','t')
           ->where('t.type IN(:array)')
```

Or am I misunderstanding your case? Then try to be a bit more clear on what result set you actually want.

### EDIT

I think you can do something like this:

```
// Main query
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->innerJoin('p.tags','t');

// Get tag repository to make tag query (you can also use FROM instead)
$tagRepository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('MyBundle\Entity\Tag');

// Choose your where
$where = 'orWhere';  //`OR` query:
$where = 'andWhere'; //`AND` query:

// Add a in sub query expression for each tag
foreach ($tags as $i => $tag){
    $alias = 't' . $i;
    $sub = $tagRepository->createQueryBuilder($alias);
    $sub->where($alias . '.key = :key' . $i);
    $sub->andWhere($alias . '.value = :value' . $i);
    $qb->setParameter('key' . $i, $tag['key']);
    $qb->setParameter('value' . $i, $tag['value']);
    $qb->$where($qb->expr()->in('t.id', $sub->getDQL()));
}

// get your resultset
return $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. To clarify, the Tag entity has two fields which must be searched for "t.key" and "t.value", hence the additional complexity.

The result set I want is either:

- "and" search: find all Photo objects which have a Tag of (key(X) AND value(Y) ) AND another Tag with key(C) AND value(D)

- "or" search: find all Photo objects which have a Tag of (key(X) AND value(Y) ) OR another Tag with key(C) AND value(D)

Comment: @TCW For example in first query you want tags with `key(A)` + `value(B)` AND `key(C)` + `value(D)`. Is A + B unique? Is C + D unique? Or is there also for example a tag with key A and value D or key C and value B?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, yes, *all 'tag pair' examples are unique* (ie. you can't have two Tags with identical key and value). [In the MySQL backend, the two columns are recorded as a unique index/key]

Comment: I updated my answer. It isn't tested, but think it should work you can leave a comment if something wrong...

Comment: Many thanks again. This is much more elegant than my original.  Some minor tweaks: $sub->setParameter needs to be $qb->setParameter (otherwise Doctrine complains about the no. of parameters not matching); plus I had to add in `$i = 1` and `$i +=1;`....**But**, unfortunately, *the result set still doesn't manage to find Photo(s) by two or more Tags*. Searching for `'photo-type'='people'` finds Photos; searching for `'people'='Bob'` finds Photos, but searching for both (using AND query) gives 0 results, despite the fact that certain Photos have both Tags. A hair-pulling moment?

Comment: @TCW I updated the answer to fix the issues you addressed. I used `$key` everywhere before but it was confusing since `key` is also used as variable so i changed to `$i` but forgot it on two spots. You should now be able to use it without the `$i = 1` and `$i += 1`. I am not sure about the issue you ran into, but it could be that it tries to find/join on one tag that satisfies all conditions. That will of course never give a result.

Comment: Frustratingly, no: I think the query tries to satisfy all conditions on one tag, which, as you say, will not produce any results.  I've not yet found another way to achieve what is needed.  Very grateful for your suggestions though!